# Adding new row/record in DevExpress AspxGridView which is Bind to DataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

My question is very simple. I want to get the newly inserted values of row and want to update GridView and my Data Source accordingly.

[image: New Record]

As shown in highlighted area in image, I want to get this **Email** and other fields in the code behind file. I am using `WebForms/VB.NET`.

Here is my **aspx** code.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True" Theme="DevEx" 
        OnDataBinding="ASPxGridView1_DataBinding" 
        OnRowUpdating="ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating"
        OnRowInserting="ASPxGridView1_RowInserting"
        OnRowInserted="ASPxGridView1_RowInserted"
        >
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                <EditButton Visible="True"/>
                <NewButton Visible="True"/>
                <DeleteButton Visible="True" />
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Email" VisibleIndex="2" Name="Email"> 
                <EditFormSettings Caption="Email" />
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="FirstName" VisibleIndex="3" Name="FirstName" />
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LastName" VisibleIndex="4" Name="LastName" />
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Password" VisibleIndex="5" Name="Password" />
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="RetryCount" VisibleIndex="6" Name="RetryCount" />
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="MaxRetryCount" VisibleIndex="7" Name="MaxRetryCount" />
        </Columns>
        <SettingsPopup>
            <EditForm Width="600" />
        </SettingsPopup>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

And this is my code behind.

```
Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_RowInserting(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs)
    Dim gridView As ASPxGridView = CType(sender, ASPxGridView)

    ' What to write here???
    e.NewValues("Email") 'doesn't give anything
    e.NewValues("Email") = "SomeEmail" 'It is also not working

End Sub
```

This link is confusing: [Inserting new Row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3711).

**Note** that I am not using `DataTable`.

Comment: then how are you providing datasource to grid. you should be able to get the values at the RowInserting event.

Comment: Using entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As i suspect you are not missing something implementation with Entity
>   Framework of AspxGridView. You are assigning EnitiyFramework
>   datasource to the grid. May be you are just creating some List
>   data source and assigning it.

I suggest you to go through the below KB and Examples. It will let you know that how to implement common scenarios when using ASPxGridView bound with EntityDataSource / Entity Framework.

**References:**

[How to implement common scenarios when using ASPxGridView bound with EntityDataSource / Entity Framework](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18504)
[How to utilize CRUD operations within ASPxGridView bound with LinqDataSource when using Anonymous Types](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3557)
[ASPxGridView bound to EntityFramework - How t update data in several tables](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q499443)

According to documentation, You will defiantly get values on the RowInserting event from e.NewValues dictionary.

**Manual CRUD Operations:**

1) Inserting:
- Handle the ASPxGridView.RowInserting event;
- Create a DataContext instance;
- Create a new DataItem and fill its properties from the e.NewValues dictionary;
- Add a new DataItem to the corresponding Table;
- Submit Changes;
- Set the eventArgs e.Cancel property to "true" to cancel an inserting operation;
- Call the ASPxGridView.CancelEdit method to close the EditForm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Close the editing form
2. Reload data on the aspxgridview (This will refresh both the
   datasource as the datagrid):

I'll put this in c# but the concept is the same:

```
protected void dxGvCatalog_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
{       
    // Here your code to save

    // Close edit form
    dxGvCatalog.CancelEdit();
    // reload Grid
    reloadAspxGridView();
}

public void reloadAspxGridView()
{
    dxGvCatalog.DataSource = Class.ConsultAll();     // Change this to your data source
    dxGvCatalog.Enabled = true;
    dxGvCatalog.Visible = true;
    dxGvCatalog.DataBind();
}
```